# Calculating the factorial without trailing zeros efficiently?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, profiling, factorial

I'm trying to improve the running time of the factorial calculation of the large number.

The first Code which simply loop over and multiplies.

```
def calculate_factorial_multi(number):
    '''
    This function takes one agruments and
    returns the factorials of that number


    This function uses the approach successive multiplication

    like 8! = 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
    '''

    '''
    If 0 or 1 retrun immediately
    ''' 
    if number == 1 or number == 0:
        return 1

    result = 1 # variable to hold the result

    for x in xrange(1, number + 1, 1):
        result *= x
    return result
```

The profiled result for this function :

> For n =  1000 -- Total time: 0.001115 s
>
> for n = 10000 -- Total time: 0.035327 s
>
> for n =  100000 -- Total time: 3.77454 s.

From the line profiler for n = 100000 i can see that most of the %time was spent in multiplication step which is '98.8'

```
31    100000      3728380     37.3     98.8         result *= x
```

So tried to reduce the multiplication in factorial
    by half, for even number, hence doing Strength Reduction.

Second half multiplication Code:

```
def calculate_factorial_multi_half(number):

    if number == 1 or number == 0:
        return 1

    handle_odd = False
    upto_number = number

    if number & 1 == 1:
        upto_number -= 1
        print upto_number
        handle_odd = True

    next_sum = upto_number
    next_multi = upto_number
    factorial = 1

    while next_sum >= 2:
        factorial *= next_multi
        next_sum -= 2
        next_multi += next_sum

    if handle_odd:
        factorial *= number

    return factorial
```

The profiled result for this function :

> For n =  1000 -- Total time: 0.00115 s
>
> for n = 10000 -- Total time: 0.023636 s
>
> for n =  100000 -- Total time: 3.65019 s

Which shows some improvement in the mid range but didn't improved much with scaling.

In this function too most of the %time is spent on multiplication.

```
61     50000      3571928     71.4     97.9         factorial *= next_multi.
```

So I tired to remove the trailing zeros and then multiply.

Without Trailing zeros code.

```
def calculate_factorial_multi_half_trailO(number):
    '''
    Removes the trailling zeros
    '''
    if number == 1 or number == 0:
        return 1

    handle_odd = False
    upto_number = number

    if number & 1 == 1:
        upto_number -= 1
        handle_odd = True

    next_sum = upto_number
    next_multi = upto_number
    factorial = 1
    total_shift = 0
    while next_sum >= 2:
        factorial *= next_multi
        shift = len(str(factorial)) - len(str(factorial).rstrip('0'))
        total_shift += shift
        factorial >>= shift
        next_sum -= 2
        next_multi += next_sum

    if handle_odd:
        factorial *= number

    factorial <<= total_shift
    return factorial
```

The profiled result for this function :

> For n =  1000 -- Total time: 0.061524 s
>
> for n = 10000 -- Total time: 113.824 s

so instead of decreasing the time it's increasing the time because of the string conversion as also '96.2%' of the time is spend on that

```
 22       500        59173    118.3     96.2        shift = len(str(factorial)) - len(str(factorial).rstrip('0')).
```

So my question is how can i get the trailing zeros and use with shift efficiently without compromising the time.

**All the profiling done on.
Elementary OS(Linux): 64bit, Ram : 6GB**

Comment: I think prime decomposition will be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Without trailing zero seems not very efficient.**

First, I suggested using [prime decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) to reduct total number of multiplications because prime numbers smaller than `x` is about `x/lnx`.

```
def calculate_factorial_multi(number):
    prime = [True]*(number + 1)
    result = 1
    for i in xrange (2, number+1):
        if prime[i]:
            #update prime table
            j = i+i
            while j <= number:
                prime[j] = False
                j += i
            #calculate number of i in n!
            sum = 0
            t = i
            while t <= number:
                sum += number/t
                t *= i
            result *= i**sum
    return result
```

> for n = 10000, total time : 0.017s
>
> for n = 100000, total time : 2.047s
>
> for n = 500000, total time : 65.324s

(PS. in your first program, for n = 100000, total time is 3.454s in my machine.)

Now let's test whether it is efficient without trailing zero. The number of trailing zero equals the number of prime factors `5` in `n!`.
The program is like this

```
def calculate_factorial_multi2(number):
    prime = [True]*(number + 1)
    result = 1
    factor2 = 0
    factor5 = 0
    for i in xrange (2, number+1):
        if prime[i]:
            #update prime table
            j = i+i
            while j <= number:
                prime[j] = False
                j += i
            #calculate the number of i in factors of n!
            sum = 0
            t = i
            while t <= number:
                sum += number/t
                t *= i
            if i == 2:
                factor2 = sum
            elif i == 5:
                factor5 = sum
            else:
                result *= i**sum

    return (result << (factor2 - factor5))*(10**factor5)
```

> for n = 10000, total time : 0.015s
>
> for n = 100000, total time : 1.896s
>
> for n = 500000, total time : 57.101s

It is just a little faster than before. So Without trailing zero seems not very useful

Comment: Can you explain a little bit about prime decomposition, how its giving correct result. I read the wiki link but is not able to understand the steps

Comment: @user4890159 Such as 10!, the number of factor 2 in 10! is `[10/2] + [10/4] + [10/8] = 8`, 3: `[10/3] + [10/9] = 4`, 5:`[10/5] = 2`, 7 : `[10/7] = 1`, so `10! = 2^8 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 7 = 3628800`

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know if this would solve your problem, but you can try this method:

I see that your requirement is factorial of 10^4 (max). So,

- Create a sieve and find all prime numbers up to 10000.
- Now, prime factorize all numbers from 1 to 10000, and store it in array. (These two steps should not take much time).
- So, you will now be having exactly 1229 primes and their powers.
- Get the powers of all primes and multiply them all. For long numbers, that will reduce number of multiply operations from 10000 to 1229. (But, at the same time it will take some time to find the powers.)

PS:  (I'm not very familiar w/ python or else I'd have done it myself)